# Bluetooth missing under System Settings

Tags: android, bluetooth, settings, android-source, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm porting bluetooth to JB (project code discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/renesas-emev-osp) and I managed to start it up, both manually (bttest enable) and through the Power Widget button. So code-wise integration seems fine, but a Bluetooth item doesn't appear, even after a full clean rebuild, under the System Settings menu. I have these set of course:

```
$ grep BLUE *.mk
BoardConfig.mk:BOARD_HAVE_BLUETOOTH := true
BoardConfig.mk:BOARD_HAVE_BLUETOOTH_BCM := true
```

but looks like it isn't enough, to enable BT settings. What did I miss?

Comment: "but a Bluetooth item doesn't appear", where do you expect it to appear?

Comment: I meant it doesn't appear in the Wireless section of System Setting menu. I can only see the Wifi menu item. I'm now trying Frank's solution (below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem recently when I compiled my own AOSP.

After a lot of trial-and-error it turned out that I was missing one option in one of these files:

---

/system/etc/permissions/handheld_core_hardware.xml

/system/etc/permissions/tablet_core_hardware.xml

---

Which file to edit depends on which file you have in the directory /system/etc/permissions.

If you have root access (which I guess) then you can even simply edit the corresponding file on your device without the need of recompiling / flashing (I personally use ES File Explorer to do that).

Just add the following line to either of these files:

```
<feature name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />
```

Then start / restart the device and bluetooth option should be enabled in the system settings.

Cheers,

Frank

Comment: Thanks Frank! It was that. I was missing /system/etc/permissions/tablet_core_hardware.xml at all from my device.mk, so it wasn't found on build target of course.

Comment: Sweet! Glad I could help out, especially since I am new to Android. Maybe the file will even help to kill some other known issues, since I believe the file is quite vital. Good luck with your project!